# Is there a way to relate a specific child view with a viewgroup?

Tags: java, android, view, expandablelistview, viewgroup

What I am trying to do is relate each child view with the viewgroup...in the code to create the child view, a new view group is created with it's elements. Are these automatically associated? I want to be able to change the number in the EditText either by the buttons, or entering the number.

Edit - this is Android/Java.

[image: ExpandableListView]

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit.   It sounds like the buttons aren't updating the editText view correctly.  This could be an issue with your code and not the expandableListView.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a child/parent issue as much as figuring out how do do this in java, i.e. converting to/from Strings and numeric values you have in the EditText.

Comment: When I implement the onClickListener for the buttons, I need to be able to know which child/group position it is in. @Maximus & @SBerg413

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the view is in a viewgroup, you can use getParent:

```
ViewGroup containter = (ViewGroup)myButton.getParent();
```

I think you want something like:

```
ViewGroup group1,group2;

onClick(View v) {
  if (v.getParent() == group1)
    ;
  else if (v.getParent() == group2)
    ;
}
```